# Enter data automatically into a web pages

Tags: web-apps, data, macros, data-entry, utility

I have a job to enter data into web pages everyday at specific times, these data are not fixed so is there a software I configure or program to enter the data for me automatically each day ?

The data are letters and numbers. I supply them myself manually. example for these data are 345rlkrty, fkdhj3542, etc....

The software can be browser based or running on Windows

it can be free or not

Comment: If you are a programmer, then see http://docs.seleniumhq.org/  If not, it will probably be too complicated for you, sorry. In which case, an you please provide some information about the kind of data? Also, do you want a browser based solution, or desktop (Which operating system)? Must it be free (use the [tag:gratis] tag). or do you have a budget? Since you are new, take a look at [ask]. The more that you can help us, by defining your problem well, the more that we can help you to find a solution. Welcome aboard :-)

Comment: I added the details

Comment: Where do those data come from, what kind of data is it, in which format is it provided?